# Will Ubuntu get an asset set to allow Qt applications using GTK style buttons?

Tags: application-development, desktop-environments

Given the recent movement towards Qt as a primary development platform for Ubuntu and the underlying Gnome standard application set:

Are there plans to have GTK style buttons available in a simple way to Qt-creator, should we expect to see the Ubuntu standard applications start to be more like Kubuntu standard applications, or something else?

*If something else, what*?

Answer (score 0):

For the widget based design approach, Qt has been using GTK for rendering them for years now. For QML, there are the [Desktop Components](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/06/06/desktop-components-for-qt-5/). So it seems like there's no need to worry.